# Axios not sending custom headers in request (possible CORS issue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, http-headers, axios

I'm encountering a problem where axios doesn't seem to send custom headers with my requests.

I'm using it like this:

```
axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: 'www.my-url.com',
  headers: { 'Custom-Header': 'my-custom-value' }
})
```

However, looking at the actual request that is sent to the server, the custom header doesn't seem to be anywhere.

```
REQUEST HEADERS:
  Accept: */*
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
  Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.9
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom-header
  Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
  Connection: keep-alive
  Host: my-url.com
```

I suspect it might be a CORS problem (the response headers don't include Custom-Header in Access-Control-Allow-Headers), but I would like to make sure before contacting the API owners about the matter.

Comment: Do you get a CORS related error message printed on the console?

Comment: Does the browser make a GET request or is it a preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: The Access-Control-Request-Headers request header is used when issuing a preflight request to let the server know which HTTP headers will be used when the actual request is made.
Why are you sending your custom header as access control ?

Comment: can you please show what exactly is your call, all the request headers you are sending.

Comment: @RonnWilder — Eh? The OP is trying to send a `Custom-Header` header. Why wouldn't the browser make a preflight request with a `Access-Control-Request-Headers: custom-header` header ahead of making the request the OP is trying to make?

Comment: I don't know exactly.
I believe that is the job of preflight request, to verify that the actual request will be fine. But can you please show all headers to analyze.

Comment: @RonnWilder [Here](https://i.imgur.com/cdp30e5.png) I have a screenshot with all the headers. The way I'm making the call is exactly like the example in the main post, but with "Access-Token" instead of "Custom-Header" as the header name. The server doesn't receive the header and returns an unauthorized error.

Comment: @Quentin No, I don't get a CORS related message. The client makes an OPTIONS preflight request, and the server returns an unauthorized error (the custom header was an access token, so that's probably the cause of the error if the header can't be sent).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Ok. so your case is preflight request.
when client tries to send a custom header, server needs to verify that it accepts that header.

so in that case, a preflight options request is sent with header Access-Control-Request-Headers. 
if server responds that it will accept the custom header. then actual request will be sent.

in your case server response header - access-control-allow-headers does not contains your custom header name.
thats why it failed.

[image]

Note: the actual POST request does not include the Access-Control-Request-* headers; they are needed only for the OPTIONS request.Read this article for more explanation - [cors - options call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 1):

Your axios request is correct. You need to allow your custom headers on server side. If you have your api in php then this code will work for you.

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");   
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Custom-Header");
```

Once you will allow your custom headers on server side, your axios requests will start working fine.